# Show that the flow with velocity vector $\vec{v}=\langle y,0,0 \rangle$ is incompressible.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator

> 1. Show that the flow with velocity vector $\vec{v}=\langle y,0,0
>     \rangle$ is incompressible. Show that the particles  at time $t=0$ are
>      in the cube whose faces are portions of the planes $ x = 0, x=  1,
>     y=  0, y=  1, z=  0, z=  1$ occupy at $t=  1$ the volume 1
> 2. Again consider, the flow with velocity vector $\vec{v}=\langle x,0,0\rangle$. Show in this case volume occupied will be $e$.

from, Continuity equation we have,

$\frac{\partial p}{dt} + div(p\vec{v}) = 0$

where $p$ is the density function and $\vec{v}$ is the velocity vector of the fluid.

clearly for given $\vec{v}$, divergence of $\vec{v}$=$\nabla .\vec{v} = 0$ so it is incompressible.

I am not sure how to prove the other part.

Is it sufficient to say that since the divergence measures outflow minus inflow of flux, and since divergence is zero in this case, outgoing flux is same as incoming and hence volume should be whole of cube $=1$.

Please help with the other part, I have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the beautiful result you need to use. Denote by $\phi_t$ the flow of your vector field $\vec v$ — i.e., $\dfrac d{dt} \phi_t(\vec x) = \vec v(\phi_t(\vec x))$. If you start with a region $\Omega$ (the unit cube, in your case), let $\Omega_t = \phi_t(\Omega)$ be the region obtained by flowing for time $t$. Then the rate at which the volume of $\Omega_t$ is changing at time $t$ is $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega_t} \text{div}\,\vec v\,dV$. (This is a variant of the divergence theorem, as the flux of $\vec v$ across the boundary of $\Omega_t$ tells you the rate at which the volume of $\Omega_t$ is changing.)

In your first example, $\text{div}\,\vec v = 0$, so the volume remains constant. In your second example, $\text{div}\,\vec v = 1$, so you must solve the ODE $\dfrac{d\,\text{vol}}{dt} = \text{vol}$.

Comment: thank you very much sir